# What is Keras doing if my sample size is smaller than my batch size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, sample-size, batchsize

fairly new to LSTM, but I already searched for a solution and could not find anything satisfying or even similar enough.

**So here is my problem:**
I am dealing with sleep classifaction and have annotated records for about 6k patients.
To train my bidirectional LSTM, I pick one patient and fit the model on that data instead of putting all the data from all the patients into one big matrix because I want to prevent patient samples mixing when Keras is training with mini batches.
The sequence length or `samples_size` per patient are not the same.
Then I loop over all patients and do a additional loop for the number of epochs I considered to train the model for (as described in [Developer Guides](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/)).
So since LSTMs (if not stateful) reset their cell and hidden state after each batch and the default `batch_size` for `tf.keras.Sequential.fit()` is 32 I wanted it to match the `sample_size` of the patient I am showing to the network. If I do so I am getting a warning and the training process errors after some time. The error is:

> WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 11 calls to .distributed_function at 0x0000023F9D517708> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings is likely due to passing python objects instead of tensors. Also, tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. Please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/eager/tf_function#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for more details.

So I looked up what my longest `sample_size` is and set my `batch_size` accordingly.

---

**tl;dr:** What is Keras doing in all the instances where my variable `sample_size` is not matching my `batch_size=max(len(sample_size))`?

1. Is it just showing the available samples to the network?

   - If so: Why is there the warning mentioned above where setting the `batch_size=sample_size` leads to the failed training?
2. Or is it showing the available samples to the network and filling up the rest with zeros to match the given `batch_size`?

   - If so: Why is there the necessity of masking when using e.g. stateful mode?

---

**edit:**
So, I tried some additional workarounds and built my own Data Generator, which proves data of one patient as one batch. I then set `steps_per_epoch=len(train_patients)` to include all patients into one epoch. No warnings about retracing, which I do not understand either.
It seems to solve my problem of showing one patient per batch without mixing patient data and have a variable `sample_size`, but I really do not understand the differences between all these posibilities and their different warnings.